# Cannot run Azure Function locally after adding a second function class in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, azure, function, azure-functions

I have a HTTP Triggered C# function in Visual Studio.
After I add a second function class via Add -> New Azure Function, I cannot run any function anymore. The Azure Function Core Tools output: "No Job functions found."

How can I choose to run one function, while have multiple functions in the project?

EDIT: Using .NET version 6, Azure Functions Version 4 and Visual Studio Community 2022

Comment: Can you share your c# http trigger code? And your visual studio code format in solution explorer?

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot to go by with your question, what .Net-version are you using? What version of Visual studio are you using? What version of Functions are you using?

You can check this by going to you Functions .csproj-file, or simply searching for your:

```
 <AzureFunctionsVersion></AzureFunctionsVersion>
```

[Is it an Isolated worker or and In-process model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=python-v2%2Cisolated-process%2Cnodejs-v4%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-csharp)?

But it sounds like you're missing a correct FunctionName, make sure you give your function a name. [You can read about FunctionName in the official Microsoft documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library?tabs=v4%2Ccmd)

> The FunctionName attribute marks the method as a function entry point. The name must be unique within a project, start with a letter and only contain letters, numbers, _, and -, up to 127 characters in length. Project templates often create a method named Run, but the method name can be any valid C# method name. The above example shows a static method being used, but functions aren't required to be static.

So if you're using an isolated worker model add a name like the following:

```
[Function(nameof(YourClass))]
```

If you're using an in-process model use:

```
[FunctionName("YourFunctionsName")]
```